# Android listview with expandable list view item

Tags: android, list, layout, view, adapter

I want to have a listview menu with few clickable elements and the last element must be an expandable list view item. I mean when I click the last element, an additional position should be expanded.

Answer (score 7):

You have three options.

- Use ExpandableListView where every group-item has no child-item and the last group-item would have child-items (they would be expanded when the parent group is clicked), there are many examples around.

  [Example of ExpandableListView](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-expandable-list-view-example/)
- Use listview and inflate views on the last item when called by getView, you know when you are loading the last position because you receive it on the function.

  [Example of listview](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)
- If you have a small number of items consider using a linearlayout to look like a listview and another linearlayout for the last item.

For example

```
  <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">     

      <TextView />

      <TextView />

      <LinearLayout 
          android:orientation="vertical" 
          android:onClik="expand">

          <TextView />

          <TextView />

      </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi could you tell me what you meant by `low`? like the exact number?

Comment: @SamzSakerz answer edited. Replaced by 'Small quantity'