# Expandable Items in ListView

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-linearlayout, expandablelistview

I am writing my self a **ListView** that will contain multiple types of items. I have done that using [ArrayAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter) and a **ListView** now my issue is that I need to have some Items inside my Adapter that is gonna expand and that will have inner items of any type. Now the issue is how can I do this? I know I can use **ExpandableListView** but I don't need some items to be expanded. I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17700251/6895166) about something similar, The person suggested to use **ExpandableListView** or a Custom Item, I would like to do the Custom Item but my concern is that the OP of the answer quoted this.

> If the number of items is low consider using a linearlayout to look
>   like a listview and another linearlayout for the last item.

I'm not sure what they mean by "low" How many items can I have inside it? Would it cause lag?

> so my question is what is the best way to do this? I need to put items
>   in a ListView that is of multiple types, and one of the types can
>   expand and have inner views that can again contain the same types and
>   so on.

Edit: Since 2 of you confused of what I want. I want to do the following inside my ArrayAdapter

```
Item
Item
Item
ExpandableItem {
   Item
   Item
   Item
   Item
}
Item
Item
```

I am trying to make some of the Items expand to have more items inside them and control the onClick of the inner items and such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About the meaning of "low": I think it's about performance but devices today are better than devices were in 2013 when the linked post was written - maybe you'll never experience a sluggish UI with your approach. Of course this depends not only on your UI structure but also on the type of data you'll be showing (videos or just text?) and on other factors like does the device have to perform heavy work in the background or not.

`RecyclerView` was developed to be a "better `ListView`", so if performance can be an issue, then maybe it is a good choice. (The adapters for both `ViewGroup`s can handle different `View` types but `RecyclerView` offers a better means of showing changes to single items and customizing change animations, another point in its favor)

> How can I do this?

- Have different `View` types for expandable and flat items
- You *can* "manually" expand/ shrink a `View` (AFAIK your only choice when working with `ListView`) by using some type of animation (or the `Transition` framework) but you always have to...
- Keep track of the expanded state of each expandable item (e.g. in the Adapter) and use them in `getView()` respectively `onBindViewHolder()`.

Comment: I can't use a `RecyclerView ` for some reason that I don't want to specify so I can only use a ListView, My idea was to create a custom view that extends View that can expand it self but I am not sure how. You mean with expand/shrink.

Comment: @SamzSakerz - I like using the Transition framework to expand ViewGroups by toggling the VISIBLE/ GONE state of certain child Views. There is a [series of posts](https://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html) by A.J. Lockwood which helped me a lot. And ListViews may have their weak spots but one can certainly work with them. The performance problems  should also be less noticeable on a modern device

Answer (score -1):

Add another ListView like RecyclerView on clicking of any item.

Comment: I don't consider this as an answer, This won't make sense. I don't want to use RecylerView. and if I use a ListView inside a ListView can you show an example how I can manage the adapters? :)